# Perl Compilation Errors Compilation failed in require at

Tags: mysql, perl, debugging

All of the sudden we have CGI errors showing up in the logs and one of the pages isn't working. I checked the syntax but I can't find the bug.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error we get in the browser:

> Archive.pl: DBD::mysql::st execute failed: SELECT command denied to user 'mnin_user'@'localhost' for table 'needs' at /home/mnin/MNN_Code/Prod/lib/MySQL.lib line 52.
>   Compilation failed in require at archive.pl line 9.

Line 47-61 of MySQL.lib reads:

```
sub RunSQL {
## Executes an sql statement on the database.
my $sqlquery = shift;

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlquery); 
$sth->execute();                #this is line 52

$MySQL_LastQuery = $sqlquery;

if ($sth->err()) {
    return 1, $sth->errstr();
} else {
    return 0, $sth->rows;
}
}
```

This is the Archvie.pl up to line 10

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # uncommenting this during debugging      phase may be helpful
#use HTML::Template;
#use Win32::ODBC;

read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

if($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST") { @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);}
else { @pairs = split(/&/, $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'});}
```

Althought I don't think the problem is in the Archive.pl becaue these Compilation errors are showing in more than one place.

Comment: This is not a problem with your code, but rather with the configuration of your database. Did you read the error message? It says _command denied to user_. Talk to your database administrator.

Comment: General tip: when code that was previously working suddenly stops working, it's good troubleshooting to think about what changed. If the code didn't change, the issue was probably caused by something else: database upgrade, OS upgrade, interpreter upgrade, server move, configuration change, etc. Thinking about what changed will help you narrow down the problem, even if you don't always have such explicit error messages as you do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> *SELECT command denied to user 'mnin_user'@'localhost' for table 'needs'*

This indicates you simply lack the permissions necessary to perform the query. At a minimum, you need the permissions granted by the following command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON `needs` TO 'mnin_user'@'localhost';
```